# Success page redirection issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5

`$this->checkoutSession->getLastSuccessQuoteId()` 
`$this->checkoutSession->getLastQuoteId()` 
`$this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId()`

These things always returns false after payment success, so i always redirect to cart page. I search over the google and every where but not found helpful. My model file is: 
 
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session/SuccessValidator.php`

```
public function isValid()
    {
        if (!$this->checkoutSession->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->checkoutSession->getLastQuoteId() || !$this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my research i have made solution for this. I made changes in Payment gateway `Controller/Response.php`. 
I have added the following code just after "Success" response.

```
$this->_checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
$this->_checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($order->getQuoteId());
$this->_checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($order->getQuoteId());
```

Issue Solved!

Comment: thanks, Jagveer for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be it will help you.

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/onepage/successs');
return $resultRedirect;
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please tell me where should i place this code. I mean  describe please. I am new to Magento

Comment: In your code may be you will put it before return true; then it will work.